# Teams proactive notifications not working

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am not getting any proactive notification to my teams bot.

After using attached references for proactive message I tried to send proactive message using bot framework emulator and added localhost url, MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword in emulator also added the MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword to proactive code, when I started process to test this app on emulator I am getting unauthorize error.
Now I'll try to host it on any web server to check this issue.

I have followed these references :
- https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/blob/master/msteams-platform/assets/downloads/SendProactiveMessages.zip
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/sbs-send-proactive?tutorial-step=3

Comment: Please refer this sample and check if it helps: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I have tried this as well, got unauthorize error same as before. Do I need to deploy my bot to azure bot service?

Comment: You can run your app locally as well, using ngrok

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have tried this and I am getting some ngrok tunnel error "Invalid tunnel configuration" .

Comment: Could you please make sure you have updated the ngrok endpoint properly in Bot Channel registration and in Manifest as well?

Comment: I created ngrok url for http://localhost:3978/api/messages and added to the bot url in teams and tried with this url  http://localhost:3978/api/messages in bot emulator.

I got same ngrok tunnel configuration issue.

Comment: Ngrok URL should be starting with http/https like https://xxx.ngrok.io so you can use like https://xxx.ngrok.io/api/messages  Please try that URL once in your configuration and check it.